# Combine: Separate logic from VM to Service

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

I'm going deep in `Combine` and truing to seperate logic from VM to Services that for reuse else where in app. I already did it with a few layers (Network calls and fetch user location) but faced the problem that can't connect `@Publishers` if logic is outside of ViewModel, but it works perfect when it in. Sorry for a lot of code...

Don't forget to add `Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description` into `Info.plist` for requesting location

**UI**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var weatherViewModel = WeatherViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                weatherViewModel.fetchLocation() }) {
                    Text("Get Location")
                }
                .buttonStyle(.bordered)
            
            Text(weatherViewModel.currentWeather?.name ?? "Nothing yet")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

**User Location**

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
import Combine

enum LocationError: Error {
    case unauthorized
    case unableToDetermineLocation
}

final class LocationManager: NSObject {
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    private var authorizationRequests: [(Result<Void, LocationError>) -> Void] = []
    private var locationRequests: [(Result<CLLocation, LocationError>) -> Void] = []

    override init() {
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
    }

    func requestWhenInUseAuthorization() -> Future<Void, LocationError> {
        guard locationManager.authorizationStatus == .notDetermined else {
            return Future { $0(.success(())) }
        }

        let future = Future<Void, LocationError> { completion in
            self.authorizationRequests.append(completion)
        }

        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        return future
    }

    func requestLocation() -> Future<CLLocation, LocationError> {
        guard locationManager.authorizationStatus == .authorizedAlways ||
                locationManager.authorizationStatus == .authorizedWhenInUse
        else {
            return Future { $0(.failure(LocationError.unauthorized)) }
        }

        let future = Future<CLLocation, LocationError> { completion in
            self.locationRequests.append(completion)
        }

        locationManager.requestLocation()

        return future
    }

    private func handleLocationRequestResult(_ result: Result<CLLocation, LocationError>) {
        while locationRequests.count > 0 {
            let request = locationRequests.removeFirst()
            request(result)
        }
    }
}

extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        let locationError: LocationError
        if let error = error as? CLError, error.code == .denied {
            locationError = .unauthorized
        } else {
            locationError = .unableToDetermineLocation
        }
        handleLocationRequestResult(.failure(locationError))
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.last {
            handleLocationRequestResult(.success(location))
        }
    }

    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        while authorizationRequests.count > 0 {
            let request = authorizationRequests.removeFirst()
            request(.success(()))
        }
    }
}
```

**Networking**

```
import Combine

final class NetworkingManager {
    
    enum NetworkingError: LocalizedError {
        case badURLResponse(url: URL)
        case unknown
        
        var errorDescription: String? {
            switch self {
            case .badURLResponse(url: let url):
                return "Bad response from URL: \(url)"
            case .unknown:
                return "Unknown Error"
            }
        }
    }
    
    static func download(url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<Data, Error> {
        return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .tryMap({ try handleURLResponse(output: $0, url: url)})
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    static func handleURLResponse(output: URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Output, url: URL) throws -> Data {
        guard let response = output.response as? HTTPURLResponse,
              response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300 else {
                  throw NetworkingError.badURLResponse(url: url)
              }
        return output.data
    }
    
    static func handleCompletion(completion: Subscribers.Completion<Error>) {
        switch completion {
        case .finished:
            break
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
struct WeatherResponseModel: Codable {
    let name: String
}
```

**And finally `ViewModel`. Here I wanna remove logic of `getCurrentWeather()` to WeatherService**

```
import Combine
import CoreLocation

final class WeatherViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentWeather: WeatherResponseModel?
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    private var weatherSubscription: AnyCancellable?
    private let locationManager = LocationManager()
    private let weatherService = WeatherService()

    func fetchLocation() {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            .flatMap { self.locationManager.requestLocation() }
            .sink { _ in
            } receiveValue: { location in
                //MARK: Works
                self.getCurrentWeather(for: location.coordinate)
                
                //MARK: Don't work, need help here!
//                self.weatherService.getWeather(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
//                self.currentWeather = self.weatherService.weather
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    //MARK: Wanna remove this logic to WeatherService
    private func getCurrentWeather(for coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=\(coordinate.latitude)&lon=\(coordinate.longitude)&appid=299279dbd985cab3b71f59d2c2593766") else { return }
        
        weatherSubscription = NetworkingManager.download(url: url)
            .decode(type: WeatherResponseModel.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: NetworkingManager.handleCompletion, receiveValue: { [weak self] (returnedWeather) in
                self?.currentWeather = returnedWeather
                self?.weatherSubscription?.cancel()
            })
    }
}
```

**And WeatherService that I try to connect in VM with other utilities but unsuccessful**

```
import Combine

final class WeatherService {
    
    @Published var weather: WeatherResponseModel?
    
    private var weatherSubscription: AnyCancellable?
    
    public func getWeather(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=\(latitude)&lon=\(longitude)&appid=299279dbd985cab3b71f59d2c2593766") else { return }
        
        weatherSubscription = NetworkingManager.download(url: url)
            .decode(type: WeatherResponseModel.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: NetworkingManager.handleCompletion, receiveValue: { [weak self] (returnedWeather) in
                self?.weather = returnedWeather
                self?.weatherSubscription?.cancel()
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @matt how to separate logic of getting weather from VM to service for reuse availability

Comment: Isn't that rather broad and architectural? I mean, sure, network request / response sounds like it should obviously be separate from a view model. And a specific often used network interaction sounds like it should be a service. But what does that have to do with Combine or any of the code you've shown? Why can't you just refactor however you like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just spotted something on your code that could be responsible of your problem.

...

**EDIT:**

```
//MARK: Don't work, need help here!
//                self.weatherService.getWeather(latitude:     location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
//                self.currentWeather = self.weatherService.weather
```

The second line isn't right because self.weatherService.weather is a var that gets updated asynchronously. You should assign the value after it gets updated. For example:

```
self.weatherService.$weather.receive(on: RunLoop.main)
        .sink(receiveValue: { updatedWeather in
self.currentWeather = updatedWeather
}).store(in: &cancellables) // Don't forget to store it!
```

Comment: code produse error on .store(in: &cancellables)... is it already stored in var weatherSubscription: AnyCancellable?

Comment: @Nizami which error? can you explain? i also edited my answer with another thing

Comment: Cannot assign value of type '()' to type 'AnyCancellable'

Comment: @Nizami, about the error, it is because the return of sink is a AnyCancellable while the result of store(in:) is Void. You are trying to save it on weatherSubscription what is causing the error. Seeing that you are using that weatherSubscription later to cancel it, it's just right what you did, so I'll edit my message. Try the new thing I posted instead.

Comment: Nope, I didn't thought it was really needed. I think that the point here is that it was an asynchronous update. There are many ways to implement an async call and I just tried to draft one quickly using what I remember. I am going to edit it.